# How to align elements on ZStack in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

### Problem

I am trying to create a view of a card with a symbol in the middle.
I tried to achieve this by creating a ZStack.
However, despite using `.center` alignment, the symbol always show in the top left.

### Code

In the following code, the `contentShape` shows on the top-left despite alignment setting.

```swift
            ZStack(alignment: .center) {
                let baseShape = RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                let contentShape = Rectangle()
                    .size(width: width, height: height)
                    .foregroundColor(getContentColor(color: card.color))
                
                baseShape.fill().foregroundColor(.white)
                baseShape.strokeBorder(lineWidth: 3, antialiased: true)
                contentShape
            }
```

[image: ZStack is aligned at top-left corner as such.]

### Question

How do I properly align the `contentShape` at the center of the ZStack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `frame` instead of `size`, because size is just for path drawing within provided rect, but rect here is entire area, so to fix use

[image: demo]

```
ZStack(alignment: .center) {
    let baseShape = RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
    let contentShape = Rectangle()
        .frame(width: width, height: height)                  // << here !!
        .foregroundColor(getContentColor(color: card.color))
    
    baseShape.fill().foregroundColor(.white)
    baseShape.strokeBorder(lineWidth: 3, antialiased: true)
    contentShape
}
```